# How to set a hotkey for minimizing a window that's snapped to the side

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

On Windows 10, without snapping a window left or right, `Windows key + Down` minimizes a window.

How do I create a hotkey that will minimize a window when the window is snapped?

> Clarifications: I need a global hotkey for any window of any program, like Chrome, File Explorer, etc... after a window has been snapped by dragging it with the mouse or using `Windows key + Right/Left`

Comment: @MátéJuhász Ty, I've posted an answer. Just a little correction: It's actually Alt+Space and N (at least in Windows 10) :)

Comment: @MátéJuhász Alt+Space and M is "Move".

Answer (score 1):

There already is a *trick* for it, no need for a new shortcut:

**WHEN THE WINDOW IS SNAPPED TO THE SIDE, AND IN FOCUS** - `Windows key + Down`, then `Windows key + Down` again will minimize it.

The first shortcut will snap the window to a quadrant, the second one will actually minimize it.

`Windows key + Up` or `Alt + Tab` will bring it back up (in its last position and size).

EDIT: Also, like MátéJuhász said, Alt+Space and N will do the same, without the quadrant bit.